# select number of records using join on three tables using single query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have Group model , User model , Ticket model

Group has_many_and_belongs_to users and user has_many tickets

```
**Groups**

id | name | user_id

**User**

id | name | group_id

**Ticket**

id | title | group_id | user_id
```

I want to retrieve count on tickets of user belonging to specific group on

particular time of intervals

I have tried this one but didn't worked.

```
select t.user_id, t.group_id ,count(t.id), (select count(t.id)
from tickets t
where created_at < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '24 hours')
from tickets t
LEFT OUTER JOIN groups ON g.id=t.group_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON u.id=t.user_id 
GROUP BY t.user_id, t.group_id;
```

How can I do this in single query?.

Thanks

Comment: MySQL and postgresql are two different prodicts. I removed a the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back you need or provide additional explanation as to why you are tagging your question with multiple product tags.

Comment: ticket_id and id in the same table ... Are you sure ? I also think user_id is missing ...

Comment: Thanks for the correction @devoh

Comment: I have to fetch counts on tickets which are assigned to particular user within 24 hours, then in between 24 hours to 36 hours and after 7 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want user_id, group_id and cnt :

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.group_id , COUNT(t.id) cnt
FROM tickets t 
WHERE t.created_at < (current_timestamp - INTERVAL '24 hours')
GROUP BY t.user_id, t.group_id
```

If you want to query by and/or retrieve user_name :

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.group_id , COUNT(t.id)
FROM tickets t 
    INNER JOIN users u 
    ON u.id = t.user_id 
        AND u.name = 'USER_NAME'
WHERE t.created_at < (current_timestamp - INTERVAL '24 hours')
GROUP BY t.user_id, t.group_id
```

If you want to query by and/or retrieve group_name :

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.group_id , COUNT(t.id)
FROM tickets t 
    INNER JOIN groups g 
    ON g.id = t.group_id
        AND g.name = 'GROUP_NAME'
WHERE t.created_at < (current_timestamp - INTERVAL '24 hours')
GROUP BY t.user_id, t.group_id
```

If you want to query by and/or retrieve user_name AND group_name :

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.group_id , COUNT(t.id)
FROM tickets t 
    INNER JOIN users u 
    ON u.id = t.user_id 
        AND u.name = 'USER_NAME'
    INNER JOIN groups g 
    ON g.id = t.group_id
        AND g.name = 'GROUP_NAME'
WHERE t.created_at < (current_timestamp - INTERVAL '24 hours')
GROUP BY t.user_id, t.group_id
```